# Wordpress CMS - is there a way to add a "gatekeeper"?

Tags: wordpress

On our old website we have a file called formcall.jsp
The file undergoes two functionality:

1. Check if any of the SYSTEMS is up [Database/Payment/..etc]
2. Check if the form relies on any of the SYSTEMS and process to allow the form or deny access to the form.

Both tables reside on Drupal/MySql table, but that's no longer possible.

We are now moving to a new website on wordpress - is there a way we can to the same as above?
Can we administer the same thing as a CMS module/gatekeeper file?

Comment: If you do not find a ready module that does what you need, you can always develop a custom WP Plugin to do what you need.

Comment: The thing is: this sounds more like a Microservices approach. WordPress itself is a monolithic application. In practice, this means having a page to check whether the database is "up" doesn't make sense. Before this page even starts to render, the WP core will realize it cannot connect to the database, show an error and won't do anything else. You will never get to see this page. You could create an independent script that tests for database connectivity first, does a sanity check on the DB and loads the WP core afterwards. Anyway, this needs to be totally redesigned from scratch for WordPress